# Is it possible for a macro on an abstract class or trait to be applied to all subclasses?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Say I have some trait (or abstract class) `Foo` in a library that is commonly extended by user code and requires some method `numArgs`:

```scala
trait Foo {
  // Number of arguments to the default constructor
  def numArgs: Int
}
```

Now `numArgs` is trivial to write but it's obnoxious boiler plate that I'd like to generate. I can do this with reflection, but it's ugly and not portable to alternative backends like ScalaJS, ScalaNative, or GraalVM.

Is it possible to write a macro annotation that I can apply *only* to `Foo` (**not** requiring it on every subclass of `Foo`) such that the method will be generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Macro annotation on abstract class (or trait) can only change ASTs of this class (trait) and its companion object. You can't change parents, children, siblings etc. It's done so that macro annotations are local in this sense.

Moreover if a trait is not sealed then its subclasses can't even be known at compile time.

If class (trait) and subclasses are nested into some object, then you can annotate the object.

If you want to modify arbitrary trees probably you need compiler plugin or code generation (generation of sources) via Scalameta.

I guess in your use case you can replace macro annotation with def macro

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def numArgs[A]: Int = macro impl[A]

def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val numArgs = weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.asClass.primaryConstructor.asMethod.paramLists.flatten.length
  q"$numArgs"
}

class A(i: Int, s: String)

numArgs[A] // 2
```

or Shapeless (if subclasses are case classes)

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Length
import shapeless.ops.nat.ToInt
import shapeless.{::, Generic, HList, HNil, Nat}

def numArgs[A] = new PartiallyApplied[A]

class PartiallyApplied[A] {
  def apply[L <: HList, N <: Nat]()(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, L], length: Length.Aux[L, N], toInt: ToInt[N]): Int = toInt()
}

case class A(i: Int, s: String)

numArgs[A]() // 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. My actual use case is a bit more complicated--I need to generate "clone" methods that can by called via dynamic dispatch, so I doubt I can pull it off with a def macro, but perhaps either just asking users to apply the macro annotation or writing a compiler plugin is the right approach. Thanks again!

Comment: @JackKoenig Actually I guess dynamic dispatch is still possible with implicit macros https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/da2489326a9194ba1de49b40441bb3d0 although writing `class A(...)(implicit val myClonableTC: MyClonableTC[A]) extends MyClonable { type Self = A }` appears to be not simpler than `@generateMyClone class A(...) extends MyClonable`.